# Filter List based on property names decided at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection

I'm wondering if is it possible to make the "property name" dynamic in the filter expressions

Consider scenario

```
List<Person> GetPerson(int countryID, int stateID, int cityID, int zip)
{
//List of person can be filtered based on below line of code
  List<Person> filteredPersons= persons.FindAll(rule => rule.CountryID == countryID).ToList();
//is it possible to specify ".Country" dynamically. something like

List<Person> filteredPersons= persons.FindAll(rule => rule."propertyName"== countryID).ToList();

}
```

Comment: You tagged `linq` but `FindAll` is a method of `Array`, not a LINQ one. Do you want a LINQ solution or any one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your example one method you could employ is using the `.Where()` extension instead of `FindAll()` this could then allow you to build your expression manually. A quick example would be as below.

```
static List<Person> GetPerson(int countryID, int stateID, int cityID, int zip)
{
    //create a new expression for the type of person this.
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person));

    //next we create a property expression based on the property named "CountryID" (this is case sensitive)
    var property = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "CountryID");

    //next we create a constant express based on the country id passed in.
    var constant = Expression.Constant(countryID);

    //next we create an "Equals" express where property equals containt. ie. ".CountryId" = 1
    var idEqualsExpr = Expression.Equal(property, constant);

    //next we convert the expression into a lamba expression
    var lExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(idEqualsExpr, paramExpr);

    //finally we query our dataset
    return persons.AsQueryable().Where(lExpr).ToList();
}
```

So this looks like alot of code but what we have basically done is manually constructed the expression tree with the end result looking similar to (and functioning as)

`return persons.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.CountryId = countryId);`

Now we can take this forward lets say you wanted to query for multiple properties using an and\or based on the method call. Ie you could change all your "filter" paramters to be Nullable and check if a value is passed in we filter for it such as.

```
static List<Person> GetPerson(int? countryID = null, int? stateID = null, int? cityID = null, int? zip = null)
{
    //create a new expression for the type of person this.
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person));

    //var equalExpression = Expression.Empty();
    BinaryExpression equalExpression = null;

    if (countryID.HasValue)
    {
        var e = BuildExpression(paramExpr, "CountryId", countryID.Value);
        if (equalExpression == null)
            equalExpression = e;
        else
            equalExpression = Expression.And(equalExpression, e);
    }
    if (stateID.HasValue)
    {
        var e = BuildExpression(paramExpr, "StateID", stateID.Value);
        if (equalExpression == null)
            equalExpression = e;
        else
            equalExpression = Expression.And(equalExpression, e);
    }
    if (equalExpression == null)
    {
        return new List<Person>();
    }

    //next we convert the expression into a lamba expression
    var lExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(equalExpression, paramExpr);
    //finally we query our dataset
    return persons.AsQueryable().Where(lExpr).ToList();
}

static BinaryExpression BuildExpression(Expression expression, string propertyName, object value)
{
    //next we create a property expression based on the property named "CountryID" (this is case sensitive)
    var property = Expression.Property(expression, propertyName);

    //next we create a constant express based on the country id passed in.
    var constant = Expression.Constant(value);

    //next we create an "Equals" express where property equals containt. ie. ".CountryId" = 1
    return Expression.Equal(property, constant);
}
```

Now this is a bit more code but as you can see we are now accepting `null` values for all our parameters and building our query for additional properties.

Now you could take this further (as assuming a more generic method is required) of passing in a `Dictionary<string, object>` of the properties \ values to query. This can be done as an extension method on an `IEnumerable<T>` as listed below.

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> CustomParameterQuery<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entities, Dictionary<string, object> queryVars)
    {
        if (entities.Count() == 0 || queryVars.Count == 0)
        {
            return entities;
        }

        //create a new expression for the type of person this.
        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        BinaryExpression equalExpression = null;
        foreach (var kvp in queryVars)
        {
            var e = BuildExpression(paramExpr, kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            if (equalExpression == null)
                equalExpression = e;
            else
                equalExpression = Expression.And(equalExpression, e);
        }

        if (equalExpression == null)
        {
            return new T[0];
        }
        //next we convert the expression into a lamba expression
        var lExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExpression, paramExpr);
        //finally we query our dataset
        return entities.AsQueryable().Where(lExpr);
    }

    static BinaryExpression BuildExpression(Expression expression, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        //next we create a property expression based on the property name
        var property = Expression.Property(expression, propertyName);

        //next we create a constant express based on the country id passed in.
        var constant = Expression.Constant(value);

        //next we create an "Equals" express where property equals containt. ie. ".CountryId" = 1
        return Expression.Equal(property, constant);
    }
}
```

Now this could be easily called as:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "CountryID", 1 },
    { "StateID", 2 }
};

var e = persons.CustomParameterQuery(dict);
```

Now obiously this is not a perfect example, but should get you moving in the right direction. Now you "could" also support "OR" statements etc by using `Expression.Or` instead of `Expression.And` when combining expressions.

**I Must add this is very error prone as it requires the Property names to be exact to the entity, you could use reflection on `T` and determine if the PropertyName exists and If it is in the correct casing.**

Comment: Thanks, Nico, it will explore this!

Answer (score 0):

Search for **System.Linq.Dynamic** in NuGet. That's the easiest way to start with Dynamic Linq.